# How to remove the app from the "Apps Using Apple ID"?

Tags: firebase, flutter, apple-login

I'm using Apple Login with Flutter/Firebase.

How can I remove my app from the "Apps Using Apple ID"?

In other words, how can I achieve the function of "Stop using Apple ID" button programmatically?

I'm using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple

The screenshots of where I asking about:

[image: Apps Using Apple ID]

[image: Stop using Aplle ID]

Comment: What do you mean by « Apps using Apple ID » ? Do you want to « logout » from Sign In with Apple programmatically ?

Comment: Yes it is a logout actually. I added screenshots to the question.

Comment: Your question is still don't clear. You can actually logout from firebase from your code and will log you out.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I want to remove the authentication permisson also. When I do the this, my app should not be listed in the "apps using apple id" section.

Comment: You can't do that... only users can, it's a privacy option that only users are concerned and I'm sure Apple will not like something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to remove your app from the listing of "App using Apple Id" within iOS settings after a user has signed out?

If a user has signed in with Apple Id before your app will show here. Even if the user has signed out via Firebase, it will show here. I believe this to be a bit of iOS functionality and not controllable by us. It is to show iOS users where they have used their Apple ID before as I believe the account will reauthenticate until removed.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205064

Comment: Here is the crack why people probably want to do it. If you re-sign-in using Apple the email will not be sent, just the User ID, forcing you to re-authenticate the user by using only the User ID. To be fair it is long and unique, but Apple doing some crazy stuff which makes life just hard for no reason again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue that developers are facing with the new Apple guidelines for using Apple Signin.  You must provide a way for the user to "delete" their account and also to revoke their Sign In status.   Apple provides only one way at the moment and that's via their [REST API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens).  It's a confusing route that I won't cover here as there are many other pages that cover it, but here is a good starting point.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708415